# upload image, then put file path into a form

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, filenames

I just need a bit of advice on what direction to go with something I am creating.

It is a simple php based webpage for our sports and social members in our office, allowing them to create, edit, view and delete events for all members to see. Events like day trips, bbq's and all kinds of things like that.

So far I have it all working as I would like, other than one thing, being the event logos.

At present, the events are all stored in a mysql database, in one table, with a column for every aspect of the event; time, date, price, venue etc etc.

I also have two columns for the event logos, one for the venue logo, and one for the general event logo.

What I need advice on, is the best way to create a page that allows a user to upload an image to the server, browse the images already uploaded, select one, and have it's file path entered into a text input when creating the event.

Could someone offer their suggestions on the best way to go about this, or offer an alternative method for selecting and inputting a logo for the event?

Thanks

Comment: why not use google-calender and its share function, or facebook groups?

Comment: Uploaded images (or their filepaths) that are not assigned to an event, and need to be browsed, are not stored in a database? They are just uploaded somewhere on the server?

Comment: hi, to be honest, it's because I want to learn by doing, i enjoy doing this kind of thing, and it means we can have the functionality we want and manage it ourselves.

Comment: @Martin, yes at the moment I think it would be better to have them uploaded to a folder as a basic file. I did toy with storing them in the data base, but could never get them to display on the page when retrieving them with php commands. if I can get that working, then that would be my preferred method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the images in the database itself.

Saved some hassle on the file path side of things.

Answer (score 1):

The [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) jQuery plugin works really well for batch and/or AJAX uploads. The way I'd handle your situation would be this:

1. Show all images on the same page with the form, and give each image a related radio button with the image path as the button's value, so the user simply checks the image they want to use,
2. If the user wants to upload images, use the Uploadify plugin and it's AJAX callback functions to dynamically populate the existing list of radio buttons.

The comment I made on your question, asking wether you store images (or their file paths) was because I think it would be much easier (and cleaner) for you to retrieve a list of uploaded images by querying a database. Personally, I don't store images in a database, only their file paths, and use PHP to handle any images that need to be deleted or moved. It's easier to assing images to other entities (especially in many-to-many relationships) that way.

If you don't want to store images' data in a separate table, I guess you'd have to use PHP file system functions to get a list of files already uploaded (`glob` comes to mind, although there could be better functions or this).

EDIT:

There is also a very good AJAX file browser plugin - [ckFinder](http://ckfinder.com/), but I have very little experience with it and can't really comment on its workflow, but if you find it to be a more elegant solution, you should try it out.

Comment: Or if you have a later php version the DirectoryIterator class is a preferred alternative to using glob. http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: I will check out what you have both mentioned above, but can you point me to any tutorial on how to correctly insert, retrieve and display images from the database? thanks

Comment: @Eds, as I mentioned in the answer, I don't store entire images in a database, so I'm not familiar with the procedure or know any tutorials (other than Googling for them, but you can do that just as well as I can). However, if you plan on relating uploaded images to entities in your database, I'd suggest that you store their file paths or just filenames if you'll be keeping them in single, controlled folders (e.g., this might be a more flexible solution if you plan on migrating servers). That way you only have to query the database for basic information that can be easily outputted in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if i could understand your question you want to associate the image with the event i.e tag the image with the event right ??
 you can use jquery's attr() function to grab the src of img and put it in input field

Comment: Hi, sorry i didnt explain very well. When the user creates an event and puts it into the database, I also want them to either upload, or selected an already uploaded image, and have the filepath entered into the database for that event. that way, when viewing the event page, it prints out the file path into an <img src=""> tag, and will display the image. hope this makes more sense.

Comment: why are you breaking this in two steps i mean first stroring event details in db n then adding image to event you could give option to upload a image in same form  where you making an event and if they want to upload the images from already selected image you can make ajax  call and retrieve already upload images and dis play then and after that you can use jquery to retrieve the img src and then uploaded everything together

Comment: I would certainly like them to pick an image or upload one as they create the event. that is my goal, but need some guidance on the best way to do it.

Comment: tell me exactly what guidance you need php code to handle upload or JavaScript ??